How to verify data copied from CD/DVD to HDD?
How can I verify that data files copied from an optical data disc (such as a CD or DVD) to a hard disk are identical?
This can easily be done for data files copied from one HDD to another using various file managers which are capable of a byte-by-byte comparison and/or creating hash files.
But how can this same task be accomplished for data files copied from CD/DVDs to HDDs?
In my experience, depending on how much the CDs/DVDs are scratched, bits flip from one read-out to the next (at least for music CDs, I don't know if this is also true for data CDs/DVDs, which is the topic of this question here). So I imagine that multiple read-outs of a file on a scratched CD/DVD would result in multiple non-identical copies of the file. Or is there a CRC32 or similar error correction code stored along with the files in the CD/DVD file system, thus preventing bad read-outs of data files ?
I know this is an issue for music CDs (which, again, are not the topic of this question), because there are multiple programs, such as Exact Audio Copy, AccurateRip, etc. which all try to prevent exactly that.
I'm wondering if the same problem applies to data discs and I am asking if there is a way to solve this problem?
How can I make sure I accurately copy the files from the CD/DVD?
Note: I am using Windows 10.

To answer your sub-question, CD-ROM disks add 288 bytes of error detection and correction for each 2048 bytes of user data (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM). You should not expect multiple reads of a file from a CD-ROM to produce different data. A badly scratched (or  decayed) disc should instead give read errors.

There should be no need to verify the data. And there is no CRC32 in the file system on a CD, but ECC on the data sectors of a CD regardless of the file system. So not much different from a hard drive.
Copying audio mode data from a 2352-byte sector is an art of it's own. There is just barely enough metadata to precisely identify a single audio sector and there is just enough error correction data to deal with small scratches when playing out the audio stream. Some CD drives are good at extracting audio, early drives were not, and that is the reason we have a multitude of audio extraction tools that try to work around the problems of the audio returned by the poor drives. Computers need to read the audio as discrete "blocks" of data, while the audio is a constant "stream" of audio data, so early drives did not work well when they were instructed to return a block of audio data, and not all drives even supported it.
But for standard data mode sectors, the 2352 bytes are divided into 16-byte header which precisely identifies the sector number, then there are 2048 bytes of user data, and 288 bytes of error correction code.
So when the CD drive is told to read a data sector to give you 2048 bytes worth of sector data, it will use the header to locate it so there can be no accidental errors reading the wrong sector, and it will also use the ECC data to fix any read errors and if there are too many errors so the data cannot be fixed or the sector ID cannot be fixed, you get a sector read error instead of incorrect data.
Still, if you are concerned, you can try to copy the files off the disk to hard drive twice, and to clear cache memory to force re-read of the data from disc, eject the disk to cause a disc change to invalidate the previously cached data already read from the drive. Then comparing the files or their hashes should be identical.
Another method is of course to try using an imaging tool to take an ISO image. And maybe take it twice and compare the results to be identical.
